# js array remove element by value using destructuring/rest syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring, rest-parameters

Seemed quite intuitive to me, but turns out that's not how things work! The goal is to remove the passed element if it exists and return the rest. I know there's a number of ways of achieving this - including `filter`: `const rest = selection.filter(i => i !== item)` - but, as I said, thought this approach would be a thing - as it is for `objects/key:value pairs`.

```
if (selection.includes(item)) {
  // remove if available
  const [item, ...rest] = selection;
  
  setSelection(rest)
} else {
  // ...
}
```

The way `destructuring` works is it assigns the `first` element of `selection` to item and assigns the rest of the items to `rest` - an array. Which is correct - that's how things work, from my understanding at least.

Is it possible to extract a specific item from an array and unpack the rest of the elements to a variable by using destructuring assignment ?

Comment: Use filter. What you are trying to do with destructuring is not possible.

Comment: you could do an ugly hack: https://jsfiddle.net/tfca7ow9/, but don't use that :P

Comment: Turns out it's possible, as shown by @NickParsons and Brett Zamir - downside being it's more work - at least with the current implementation.

Comment: @Omkar76 I definitely used filter - just thought there could be a more "elegant" way. I also didn't want to conclude with `not possible` before I heard from the community

Comment: @colinwagaba, I get your point. I didn't think about destructuring array to an object. I know I should be more careful saying *not possible* next time =)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a strange way it could be done:

```
const item = 5
const selection = [3, 4, 5, 6]
const itemPos = selection.indexOf(item)

if (selection.includes(item)) {
  // remove if available
  const {[itemPos]: item, ...rest} = selection

  // `rest` is now an object, so convert back to an array:
  console.log(Object.values(rest)) // [3, 4, 6]
  setSelection(Object.values(rest))
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Since I used `const` in both places, the second `item` is a different one, but one could remove `const` and wrap the expression in parentheses to reassign `item` (as I think you had originally requested):

```
let rest, item = 5
const selection = [3, 4, 5, 6]
const itemPos = selection.indexOf(item)

if (selection.includes(item)) {
  // remove if available
  ({[itemPos]: item, ...rest} = selection)
  console.log(Object.values(rest)) // [3, 4, 6]
  setSelection(Object.values(rest))
} else {
  // ...
}
```

But if you wanted to follow a similar pattern without using `filter`, you could use `splice`:

```
const item = 5
const selection = [3, 4, 5, 6]
const itemPos = selection.indexOf(item)

if (selection.includes(item)) {
  // remove if available
  const rest = [...selection] // Copy array if you still need `selection`; otherwise, we could just splice and pass `selection`
  rest.splice(itemPos, 1)
  console.log(rest)
  setSelection(rest)
} else {
  // ...
}
```

None of these are especially appealing compared to `filter`, but it should show how the approaches would work.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to be aware that **arrays** in JS can be treated as **objects**.

As you can see here:

```js
console.log(typeof [0,1,2])
```

Okay, so... now if we read the syntax of [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) we can see that there is the possibility to extract an specific element from an object by using its **key**.

> const { [key]: a } = obj

For example:

```js
const arr = ["", "", ""]

const { [0]: a } = arr

console.log(a)
```

The  gets extracted and assigned to `a` by using `0` as the **key**, which is the **index** of this item in the array.

... by combining the previews syntax with the following, it is possible to unpack the rest of the elements of the array to a variable

> const { a, b, ...rest } = obj

```js
const arr = ["", "", ""];

const {[2]: a, ...rest} = arr

console.log(Object.values(rest))
```

Due to the array being treated as an object it's necessary to use `Object.values()` to convert the `rest` object, with the unpacked elements, back to an array.

In case your variables have already been declared, wrap the variable names in brackets so that the JS can parse correctly:

```js
let a, rest, arr = ["", "", ""];

({[1]: a, ...rest} = arr)

console.log(Object.values(rest))
```